# C Valgrind stacktrace fail, linear malloc array of structures

Tags: c, memory, data-structures, valgrind

Here is a C program I was looking to create which monitors a set number of dynamically allocated structures (created at the time of initialization of the program).  The structures have the bare-bone requirements for now (fd).

Effectively,

1. It initializes the memory for N structures
2. Fills them in
3. Searches through them for matching file descriptors
4. Match where appropriate and does loop around if there are too many

The problem lies with valgrind... I don't know what I am doing wrong with my pointers, structures etc...

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define NO_ERROR 0
#define DEFAULT_ERROR -1

typedef struct dev_conn_state_s {
    int fd;
} dev_con_state_t;

int current_elements = 0;
int max_elements = 0;

int init_datastruct_commhandler(int size, dev_con_state_t ** conn_list);
dev_con_state_t *new_datastruct_commhandler_element(int fd, dev_con_state_t * conn_list);
dev_con_state_t *search_datastruct_commhandler_element(int fd, dev_con_state_t * conn_list);

dev_con_state_t *build_insert_element(dev_con_state_t * conn_list, int fd);
dev_con_state_t *build_search_element(dev_con_state_t * conn_list, int fd);

void set_max_conns(int max);
extern inline int get_max_conns(void);

/**
 * init_datastruct_commhandler(int size, dev_con_state_t ** conn_list)
 * 
 * @brief initializes large heap and buffer for each device to be tracked
 * @param size
 * @param conn_list
 * @return (-1) for error, 0 for success
 */
int init_datastruct_commhandler(int size, dev_con_state_t ** conn_list)
{
    printf("Init datahandler memory heap\n");

    // Quick param check
    if (size <= 0) {
        return DEFAULT_ERROR;
    }
    current_elements = 0;
    *conn_list = malloc(sizeof(dev_con_state_t) * size);

    // Check if malloc failed
    if (*conn_list == NULL) {
        printf("stack malloc failed\n");
        return DEFAULT_ERROR;
    }

    memset(*conn_list, 0, sizeof(dev_con_state_t) * size);

    printf("Completed datahandler memory heap\n");

    return NO_ERROR;
}

/**
 * build_insert_element(dev_con_state_t *conn_list, struct sockaddr_rc in_addr)
 * @brief Build a static element in the heap and insert
 * @param conn_list
 * @param fd
 * @param in_addr
 * @param conn if built
 */
dev_con_state_t *build_insert_element(dev_con_state_t * conn_list, int fd)
{
    //~ dev_con_state_t conn = { 0 };
    //~ printf("ob %p\n",fd);
    //~ conn.fd = fd;
    //conn.last_activity = time(NULL);
    printf("a %p %p\n",conn_list,&conn_list);

    return new_datastruct_commhandler_element(fd, conn_list);
}

/**
 * build_search_element(dev_con_state_t *conn_list)
 * @brief Build a static element in the heap and search
 * @param conn_list
 * @param fd
 * @param in_addr
 * @param conn if built
 */
dev_con_state_t *build_search_element(dev_con_state_t * conn_list, int fd)
{

    return search_datastruct_commhandler_element(fd, conn_list);
}

/**
 * new_datastruct_commhandler_element(dev_con_state_t * conn, dev_con_state_t * conn_list)
 * 
 * @brief Adds new datastruct to connection tracker heap
 * @param conn
 * @param conn_list
 * @return (-1) for error, 0 for success
 */
dev_con_state_t *new_datastruct_commhandler_element(int fd, dev_con_state_t * conn_list)
{

    //int size = sizeof(dev_con_state_t) * current_elements;
    printf("%p %p\n",conn_list,&conn_list);

    dev_con_state_t *tmp = conn_list + (sizeof(dev_con_state_t) * current_elements);

    int last_elements = current_elements;

    if (current_elements == (max_elements)) {
        tmp->fd = fd;
        current_elements = 0;
    } else {
        tmp->fd = fd;
        current_elements++;
    }

    return (dev_con_state_t *) conn_list + (sizeof(dev_con_state_t) * last_elements);
}

/**
 * search_datastruct_commhandler_element(dev_con_state_t * conn, dev_con_state_t * conn_list)
 * 
 * @brief Searches for datastruct in connection tracker heap
 * @note  USES FD (file descriptor) for NOW!
 * @param conn
 * @param conn_list
 * @return NULL for error, non-NULL for success (aka the element we were tracking)
 */
dev_con_state_t *search_datastruct_commhandler_element(int fd, dev_con_state_t * conn_list)
{
    int i = 0;
    dev_con_state_t *tmp = NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < get_max_conns(); i++) {
        tmp = (conn_list + (sizeof(dev_con_state_t) * i));

        if (tmp->fd == fd) {
            return ((dev_con_state_t *) conn_list + (sizeof(dev_con_state_t) * i));
        }

    }
    return (NULL);
}

/**
 * cleanup_connection_tracker(dev_con_state_t **conn_list)
 * 
 * @brief Cleanup connection tracker function
 * @param conn_list
 */
void cleanup_connection_tracker(dev_con_state_t ** conn_list)
{

    if (*conn_list != NULL) {
        free(*conn_list);
        *conn_list = NULL;
    }
}

/**
 * set_max_conns(int max)
 * @brief set max
 * @param max
 */
void set_max_conns(int max)
{
    max_elements = max;
}

/**
 * get_max_conns(void)
 * @brief get max
 * @return max
 */
inline int get_max_conns(void)
{
    return max_elements;
}

//#ifdef CODE_TEST
#define MAX_DEVS 8
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int size = MAX_DEVS;
    dev_con_state_t *conn_list = NULL;

    printf("initial address: %p\n", conn_list);
    printf("initial address: %p\n", &conn_list);

    set_max_conns(size);

    if (init_datastruct_commhandler(size, &conn_list) < 0) {
        return (-1);
    }
    printf("init address: %p\n", conn_list);
    printf("init address: %p\n", &conn_list);

    dev_con_state_t conn_array[MAX_DEVS] = { 0 };

    dev_con_state_t *ptr = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < get_max_conns(); i++) {
        conn_array[i].fd = i;
        //~ if ((ptr = new_datastruct_commhandler_element(conn_array[i].fd, conn_list)) == NULL) {
        //~ return (-1);
        //~ }
        /// test will error -> we looped around
        if ((ptr = build_insert_element(conn_list, conn_array[i].fd)) == NULL) {
            printf("error finding element\n");
        } else {
            printf("found: %d\n", ptr->fd);
        }

        printf("inserted: %d\n", ptr->fd);
    }

    if ((ptr = search_datastruct_commhandler_element(conn_array[5].fd, conn_list)) != NULL) {
        printf("found: %d\n", ptr->fd);
    } else {
        printf("NOT found: %d\n", conn_array[5].fd);
    }

    if ((ptr = search_datastruct_commhandler_element(conn_array[3].fd, conn_list)) != NULL) {
        printf("found: %d\n", ptr->fd);
    } else {
        printf("NOT found: %d\n", conn_array[3].fd);
    }

    /// Still visible out here?
    //~ dev_con_state_t *ptr2 =(&conn_list + sizeof(dev_con_state_t));
    //~ printf("test: %d\n", ptr2->fd);

    /// test for searching for last element
    if ((ptr = build_search_element(conn_list, conn_array[6].fd)) == NULL) {
        printf("error finding element\n");
    } else {
        printf("found: %d\n", ptr->fd);
    }

    /// test for finding a number that doesnt exist
    if ((ptr = build_search_element(conn_list, 9)) == NULL) {
        printf("error finding element\n");
    } else {
        printf("found: %d\n", ptr->fd);
    }

    if ((ptr = build_insert_element(conn_list, conn_array[6].fd)) == NULL) {
        printf("error finding element\n");
    } else {
        printf("inserted: %d\n", ptr->fd);
    }

    /// test will error -> we looped around
    if ((ptr = build_search_element(conn_list, conn_array[0].fd)) == NULL) {
        printf("error finding element\n");
    } else {
        printf("found: %d\n", ptr->fd);
    }

    cleanup_connection_tracker(&conn_list);

    printf("Done\n");
    return (0);
}

//#endif
```

I have no idea, whats causing this... Is it something from my malloc or the way I am performing my arithmitic?

```
 valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes ./test
==27353== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==27353== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==27353== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==27353== Command: ./test
==27353== 
initial address: (nil)
initial address: 0xffefffdc8
Init datahandler memory heap
Completed datahandler memory heap
init address: 0x5202040
init address: 0xffefffdc8
a 0x5202040 0xffefffd78
0x5202040 0xffefffd40
found: 0
inserted: 0
a 0x5202040 0xffefffd78
0x5202040 0xffefffd40
found: 1
inserted: 1
a 0x5202040 0xffefffd78
0x5202040 0xffefffd40
==27353== Invalid write of size 4
==27353==    at 0x400784: new_datahub_commhandler_element (test.c:119)
==27353==    by 0x4006E9: build_insert_element (test.c:80)
==27353==    by 0x400968: main (test.c:213)
==27353==  Address 0x5202060 is 0 bytes after a block of size 32 alloc'd
==27353==    at 0x4C2BBCF: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27353==    by 0x400656: init_datahub_commhandler (test.c:49)
==27353==    by 0x4008D3: main (test.c:197)
==27353== 
==27353== Invalid read of size 4
==27353==    at 0x400984: main (test.c:216)
==27353==  Address 0x5202060 is 0 bytes after a block of size 32 alloc'd
==27353==    at 0x4C2BBCF: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27353==    by 0x400656: init_datahub_commhandler (test.c:49)
==27353==    by 0x4008D3: main (test.c:197)
==27353== 
found: 2
==27353== Invalid read of size 4
==27353==    at 0x40099B: main (test.c:219)
==27353==  Address 0x5202060 is 0 bytes after a block of size 32 alloc'd
==27353==    at 0x4C2BBCF: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27353==    by 0x400656: init_datahub_commhandler (test.c:49)
==27353==    by 0x4008D3: main (test.c:197)
==27353== 
inserted: 2
a 0x5202040 0xffefffd78
0x5202040 0xffefffd40
found: 3
inserted: 3
a 0x5202040 0xffefffd78
0x5202040 0xffefffd40
found: 4
inserted: 4
a 0x5202040 0xffefffd78
0x5202040 0xffefffd40
found: 5
inserted: 5
a 0x5202040 0xffefffd78
0x5202040 0xffefffd40
found: 6
inserted: 6
a 0x5202040 0xffefffd78
0x5202040 0xffefffd40
found: 7
inserted: 7
==27353== Invalid read of size 4
==27353==    at 0x4007EA: search_datahub_commhandler_element (test.c:142)
==27353==    by 0x4009CC: main (test.c:222)
==27353==  Address 0x5202060 is 0 bytes after a block of size 32 alloc'd
==27353==    at 0x4C2BBCF: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==27353==    by 0x400656: init_datahub_commhandler (test.c:49)
==27353==    by 0x4008D3: main (test.c:197)
==27353== 

valgrind: m_mallocfree.c:303 (get_bszB_as_is): Assertion 'bszB_lo == bszB_hi' failed.
valgrind: Heap block lo/hi size mismatch: lo = 4, hi = 17179869184.
This is probably caused by your program erroneously writing past the
end of a heap block and corrupting heap metadata.  If you fix any
invalid writes reported by Memcheck, this assertion failure will
probably go away.  Please try that before reporting this as a bug.


host stacktrace:
==27353==    at 0x38083F98: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==27353==    by 0x380840B4: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==27353==    by 0x38084241: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==27353==    by 0x38091AEC: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==27353==    by 0x3807D653: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==27353==    by 0x3807BEE3: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==27353==    by 0x380800BA: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==27353==    by 0x3807B47A: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==27353==    by 0x380593E1: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==27353==    by 0x802D490EB: ???
==27353==    by 0x802CA9F2F: ???
==27353==    by 0x80200831F: ???
==27353==    by 0x4009CC: main (test.c:222)

sched status:
  running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable (lwpid 27353)
==27353==    at 0x4009DC: main (test.c:223)


Note: see also the FAQ in the source distribution.
It contains workarounds to several common problems.
In particular, if Valgrind aborted or crashed after
identifying problems in your program, there's a good chance
that fixing those problems will prevent Valgrind aborting or
crashing, especially if it happened in m_mallocfree.c.

If that doesn't help, please report this bug to: www.valgrind.org

In the bug report, send all the above text, the valgrind
version, and what OS and version you are using.  Thanks.
```

Any help would be amazing! I'm smashing my head on the keyboard... It appears to work. As given this output

```
    ./test 
initial address: (nil)
initial address: 0x7fff41386a68
Init datahandler memory heap
Completed datahandler memory heap
init address: 0x650010
init address: 0x7fff41386a68
a 0x650010 0x7fff41386a18
0x650010 0x7fff413869e0
found: 0
inserted: 0
a 0x650010 0x7fff41386a18
0x650010 0x7fff413869e0
found: 1
inserted: 1
a 0x650010 0x7fff41386a18
0x650010 0x7fff413869e0
found: 2
inserted: 2
a 0x650010 0x7fff41386a18
0x650010 0x7fff413869e0
found: 3
inserted: 3
a 0x650010 0x7fff41386a18
0x650010 0x7fff413869e0
found: 4
inserted: 4
a 0x650010 0x7fff41386a18
0x650010 0x7fff413869e0
found: 5
inserted: 5
a 0x650010 0x7fff41386a18
0x650010 0x7fff413869e0
found: 6
inserted: 6
a 0x650010 0x7fff41386a18
0x650010 0x7fff413869e0
found: 7
inserted: 7
found: 5
found: 3
found: 6
error finding element
a 0x650010 0x7fff41386a18
0x650010 0x7fff413869e0
inserted: 6
found: 0
Done
```

Comment: Please construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Oliver, I updated it.

Comment: Please read up on how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  Note that an MCVE must either be self-contained (it generates or contains its own data) or the data used must be specified.  The errors reported seem straight-forward.  Valgrind is spotting that you are writing beyond the end of an allocated structure.  You appear to have: `dev_con_state_t *tmp = conn_list + (sizeof(dev_con_state_t) * current_elements);` — why are you multiplying by the size?  C already scales pointer arithmetic by the size of the object.  You mean `dev_con_state_t *temp = conn_list + current_elements;`, I believe.

Comment: Hello Jonathan, thanks for the solid comment.  I think it I need to multiply as without that conn_list is a linear segment of memory and merely saying, that there is 5 elements will only increment a ptr 5 bytes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for my simplest solution as was given by some of the epic comments here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

typedef struct mystruct_s {
    int fd;
    int a;
    int b;
} mystruct_t;

int current_elements = 0;
int max_elements = 0;

int init(int size, mystruct_t ** conn_list)
{
    if (size <= 0) {
        return (-1);
    }
    current_elements = 0;

    *conn_list = malloc(max_elements *sizeof(mystruct_t));

    if (*conn_list == NULL) {
        return (-1);
    }

    return (0);
}

void insert(int fd, mystruct_t ** conn_list, mystruct_t ** res)
{

    *res = NULL;

    if (current_elements == (max_elements)) {
        (*conn_list)[current_elements].fd = fd;
        (*conn_list)[current_elements].a = fd;
        (*conn_list)[current_elements].b = fd;
        *res = &(*conn_list)[current_elements];
        current_elements = 0;
    } else {
        (*conn_list)[current_elements].fd = fd;
        (*conn_list)[current_elements].a = fd;
        (*conn_list)[current_elements].b = fd;
        *res = &(*conn_list)[current_elements];
        current_elements++;
    }
}

int search(int fd, mystruct_t ** conn_list, mystruct_t ** res)
{
    int i = 0;
    if (*conn_list == NULL) {
        *res = NULL;        
        return (-1);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < max_elements; i++) {
        if ((*conn_list)[i].fd == fd) {
            *res = &(*conn_list)[i];
            return (1);
        }

    }
    *res = NULL;
    return (-1);
}

#define MAX_ELEMENTS 8
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int size = MAX_ELEMENTS;
    mystruct_t conn_array[MAX_DEVS] = { 0 };
    mystruct_t *conn_list = NULL;

    max_elements = MAX_DEVS;

    if (init(size, &conn_list) < 0) {
        return (-1);
    }

    mystruct_t *ptr = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < max_elements; i++) {
        conn_array[i].fd = i;
        insert(conn_array[i].fd, &conn_list, &ptr);
    }

    if ((search(conn_array[5].fd, &conn_list, &ptr)) > 0) {
        printf("Found: %d\n", ptr->fd);
    } else {
        printf("NOT found: %d\n", conn_array[5].fd);
    }

    if (conn_list != NULL) {
        free(conn_list);
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Your pointer arithmetic is still wrong. There is no need to multiply by the size of an element. Why are using pointer arithmetic at all? Arrays in C have a perfectly good indexing operator. `conn_list[i]` is all you need.

Comment: @n.m do tell why an array would be better?  they are not dynamic in this case and may need to change. Unless you are referring to an array of pointers?

Comment: "why an array would be better"? `malloc (n * sizeof(mystruct_t))` allocates space for an array of `n` elements of type `mystruct_t`, and returns a pointer to its first element. Now you have a choice of using it correctly or incorrectly. `conn_list[i]` would be an example of correct usage. So would be `*(conn_list + i)`, which is **by definition** equivalent to the previous example. `*(conn_list + i * sizeof(mystruct_t))` is an example of incorrect usage. `conn_list[i]` is easy to read and easy to write. What you have wrote is neither, on top of being incorrect.

Comment: @n.m Excellent, I've updated this.  Is there a nicer way of writing: (*conn_list)[current_elements].fd = fd;

Comment: If `conn_list` is a `dev_con_state_t**`, then no, there's no nicer way. You can write `conn_list[0][current_elements]`, but this is hardly an improvement.